# How to copy a table into excel with bullets and keep the bullets in the same format that it was in ms-word

Tags: excel, ms-word

Not sure if this is the right place for this.

I am trying to copy a table that is in word that has bulleted lists in cells and paste it in excel, keeping the bulleted lists in their respective tells. For example I want the ms-word table 1 to paste into excel like it is in excel-1, but in reality it is pasting as shown in excel-2.

ms-word table 1
[image: ms-word table 1]

excel-1
[image: excel-1]

excel-2
[image: excel-2]

I have tried both pasting it in without clicking into the cell(double clicking), and just single clicking the cell and pasting.

I have not tried a coding option for this, but if I did I would want to do it in javascript.

It should copy the table exactly how it is in the table in word into the cells in excel.

Comment: You'll need to copy the bulleted cells individually and paste it into the formula bar of the selected cell, otherwise Excel will attempt to divide them among a series of cells.

Comment: No, this is not the right place for a non-programming question. Try Super User.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid VBA, here's a manual workaround that uses a temporary substitution of newline characters during the copy process:

- In Word, select the table, use Find/Replace (ctrl-h) to replace all newlines:

  - Find what: ^p (new paragraph mark)
  - Replace with: | (pipe - or any dummy placeholder)
- Copy the table and paste into excel using the Match Destination Formatting option (unfortunately, keeping the large bullet points isn't possible as Excel stores them as characters from a different font which breaks the next find/replace)
- In Excel, use Find/Replace to fix the desired spacing before and after the leading bullet point in every cell (which is now stored as all spaces)
- Copy a bullet point with the desired leading/trailing spaces
- Use Find/Replace again to reinsert newlines:

  - Find what: |
  - Replace with: paste in the bullet point with leading/trailing spaces, then press ctrl-shift-j to enter a newline character (can also be entered using alt+0010)
- Autofit all rows to see the cells split back into multiple lines